# NSMutableSet Not adding object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutableset

My code isn't adding elements to my sets.

My header file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NHPSearchViewController : UITableViewController
//For using the local DB
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
//texst field where user enters a substance name or a drug name
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *substanceTextField;

//An array for Drug Names, and another array for NHPs 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *drugList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *NHPList;
//Contains both drugList and NHP list as one array for the data to be shown for the user.
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *usersList;

@end
```

My .m file:

```
@interface NHPSearchViewController ()
- (BOOL) checkAndAddToList: (NSString *) substance;
@end

@implementation NHPSearchViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize substanceTextField;
@synthesize drugList, NHPList, usersList;

//"Private" helper methods

-(BOOL) checkAndAddToList:(NSString *)substance{
    //  Set up a predicate for testing if the data exists in the table
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", substance];    

    //Run the query to see if the substance is in the Substances Table.
    NSMutableArray  *results =[NSMutableArray array];
    results = [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsForEntity:@"Substances" withPredicate:pred andSortKey:nil andSortAscending:NO andContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        if ([results count] > 0){
        //Found the substance return YES
            Substances *sub = [results objectAtIndex:0];        
            NSLog(@"Did find a result with name:%@  and class_name as:%@ ",[sub name], [sub class_name]);

            //add the name to the appropriate lists.
            if([[sub class_name] isEqualToString:@"NHP"]){
                NSLog(@"NHP was found adding it to the nhp list");
                [NHPList addObject:[sub name]];  //THIS is not working
                NSLog(@"NHP count after adding %i", [NHPList count]);
            }else if ([[sub class_name] isEqualToString:@"Drugs"]){
                NSLog(@"Drug was found adding it to the drug list");
                [drugList addObject:[sub name]];  //THIS is also not working
            }

            //add the name to our list in the view
            [usersList addObject:[sub name]]; //This is also not working

            return YES;
    }else{
      // 
       return YES;

    }
 return NO;
}
```

The log output:

> [4187:fb03] Testing substanceTextField value: Omega 3-6-9 [4187:fb03]
>   Did find a result with name:Omega 3-6-9  and class_name as:NHP 
>   [4187:fb03] NHP was found adding it to the nhp list [4187:fb03] NHP
>   count after adding 0 [4187:fb03] NHP List:0 DrugList:0 UserList:0

Comment: Try:  `[self.NHPList addObject:[sub name]];` and also make sure that self.NHPList is not nil.

Comment: Did you check the second part of my comment?  Is NHPList nil?  (This is the same question that @bandejapaisa is asking)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At some point before you use the set, you need to create a new NSMutableSet.

To make it easy, you can use something like the following to automatically allocate a new mutable set when you ask to use it for the first time.

```
- (NSMutableSet *)NHPList {
    if (NHPList == nil) {
        NHPList = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return NHPList;
}
```

You would also have to release the memory, usually in your `viewDidUnload` method by setting `NHPList` to `nil`.

If this is the only place that you set the data, you could also just change this line:

```
[NHPList addObject:[sub name]];
```

to:

```
if (self.NHPList == nil) {
    self.NHPList = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
}
[self.NHPList addObject:[sub name]];
```

Comment: You will need to do the same thing for drugList and usersList.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialised NHPList ?

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C, but isn't that what the synthesize does? If i do have to initialize it myself how would I do it? and would I need to release the memory manually as well?

Comment: No, synthesize creates the setters and getters for you (which contain some code for memory management). Are you using ARC - memory would be handled for you when you create and initialise and you wouldn't need to release the memory in dealloc. See @Inafziger answer for the code used to create the NHPList variable. Probably good idea to look through some Apple sample code and read the Objective-C programming guide.